# How to obtain power set?

Tags: matlab

I would like to consider power set in my code. I want to have in each loop, I obtain a subset of `{1,2,3,...,n}`. For example, `n=3`. In the first one loop, I would like to extract the number 1 and store in a variable `Index`. Ultimately, I want to obtain `Index=2` in the second loop, `Index=3` in the third loop, `Index=[1,2]` in the fourth loop, `Index=[1,3]` in the fifth loop, `Index=[2,3]` in the sixth loop and , `Index=[1,2,3]` in the seventh loop. Of course I would like that `n` can be any arbitrary number, say it can be 100. I can think of listing all the cases, but are there any ways to achieve my task?

Comment: Check this: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62752-powerset-s

Comment: For `n=100` you'll have over 10^30 different combinations. Are you sure you really need all those listed out, or do you just need to access arbitrary values from the list?

Comment: All combinations.

Comment: Assuming you generate 1 combination every nanosecond, for `n=100` it would take about 100,000,000,000,000 years to list them all. Are you sure you have that kind of time? I think you should reconsider your approach to whatever problem it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also, unless you tag someone like @beaker, they won't be notified (with a few exceptions, like the author of the post).

Answer (score 1):

nchoosk should find all k-long combinations. I suggest the following solution:

```
n = 3;
index = {};
for ii = 1:n
    k = nchoosek(1:n,ii);
    c = num2cell(k,2);
    index(end+1:end+length(c),1) = c;
end
```

Another approach is to use a binary system where 001 means that you take only 1, 011 equals [1,2], 111 equals [1,2,3] etc. Then you can get it with dec2bin with no loop:

```
isChosen = dec2bin(1:2^n-1) == '1';
```

However, if we you must have it as a cell array you loop through the rows:

```
index1 = {};
for ii = 1:size(isChosen,1)
    index1{ii,1} = find(isChosen(ii,:));
end
```

And then, if you insist on a sensible order:

```
[~,order] = sort(cellfun(@sum,index1));
index1 = index1(order);
```